How to avoid interpolation in button_press_event of plot?
For horizontal axis of my plot I have int64 type numpy array.
Then I've linked button press event to the plot:
plt.connect("button_press_event", on_click)

This is the handler
def on_click(event):
    cursor_x = event.xdata
    ...

What I see is non-integer interpolated xdata. How can I avoid interpolation and get the nearest datapoint from x axis in handler function?

I recommend not handling the plot event yourself. There are packages that already handle this well. See this answer for example.
Finding the nearest value can then be handled separately, like in this answer.
